# What happens after using the "recommend deletion" option, when doing reviews?

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer, review-queues

When I'm reviewing answers that show up as low quality, and I've read the low-quality answer and agree that it's delete-worthy - e.g. there's no IPS solution in it or the answer is 2 or 3 sentences long - I've been using the "**recommend deletion**" option.  Then the queue gets cleared when I'm done reviewing.

What actually happens to the answers that I recommend deleting?  Do they go to a diamond moderator for another round of reviews, or is it automatically deleted, after another reviewer recommends deleting the answer, too?

To be clear, I don't have enough rep to cast *delete votes* -- I am referring only to working on the review queues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **What actually happens to the answers that I recommend deleting?**

When it gets six *Recommend Deletion* clicks, this answer will be deleted and will be shown as

> Deleted from review by [users' names who voted to Recommend Deletion] [date of deletion] at [time of deletion]

See [this item](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/858) for above scenario,

[image]

Remember, this button text is changed for users with expanded delete vote privileges (>4k on this site currently). In this case, if 3 users with those privileges (or a moderator) vote to delete that post, it will be deleted and will be shown as

> Deleted by [users] [date of deletion] at [time of deletion]

See [this item](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/8289),

[image]

Number of hours or minutes will be shown instead of date and time, depending how much time is gone after deletion of that post.

Another **point to note**, the numbers I mentioned above will work for the posts with zero or less score. The higher the score a post has, more votes will be required to delete it.

> **Do they go to a diamond moderator for another round of reviews, or is it automatically deleted, after another reviewer recommends deleting the answer, too?**

They don't go in the queue for diamond moderators. And they do get deleted by the process I mentioned above.

Comment: *Six* recommend deletion clicks?  That sounds a bit high, especially during a time when we're trying to moderate the answers more heavily, e.g. discourage NAA / VLQ posts.  This would be one aspect of site policy that I'd like to see change immediately - I wonder whether most of the community would agree, too.

Comment: There is no need of it. Six Recommend Clicks is only required when a post doesn't get reviews from enough users with expanded deletion privileges. I haven't seen that on this site in a while though.

Comment: Recommend Deletion reviews prioritize the review task for users who do have delete-voting privileges. Also, if a post with a positive score gets six reviews, it won't be deleted, but forwarded to moderators for review.